# C++ Runtime Error 0xC0000005 Caused By Object Inside Struct

Tags: c++, runtime-error

While working on a C++ project, a runtime error (0xC0000005) showed up. I managed to locate the problem and encapsulate it in the code below.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class TestC{
    public:
    string test1[20];
    string test2[10];

    void initArrays(){
        cout << "init start\n";
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
            cout << i << endl;
            this->test1[i] = "initialized";
        }
        cout << "first for complete\n";
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            this->test2[i] = "initialized";
        cout << "init finished\n";
    }
};


struct TestS{
    int anint;
    int anotherint;
    TestC obj;
};


int main(){

    cout<<"Check :\n";
    struct TestS *struct_instance = (struct TestS*) malloc(sizeof(struct TestS));
    struct_instance->obj.initArrays();
    cout<<"Ok Struct";

    return 0;
}
```

Basically the error is only thrown when `initArrays()` is called through the `TestC` object located inside `struct TestS`.

If `initArrays()` is called from an object created inside `main()`, like below, everything works fine.

```
int main(){
    TestC classObj;
    classObj.initArrays();
}
```

Despite being able to locate the problem, I have been unsuccessful in fixing it.

Does anyone know what would do the trick?

*I am using the Code::Blocks IDE*

**NOTE:** Creating the `TestC` object in `main()` and only maintaining a pointer to it within the struct, is not a suitable solution for the actual project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `malloc` to allocate a structure that contains a class, `TestC`. This means the `TestC` constructor won't run and the `test1` and `test2` arrays won't be correctly initialized.

Instead, use `new`:

```
TestS *struct_instance = new TestS;
```

You should **never** use `malloc` to allocate and type that is a C++ class, or contains a C++ class.

Comment: And then you shouldn't really be using new/delete either. Your code actually misses the delete and thus already has a memory leak. use : auto struct_instance  = std::make_unique<TestS>(); Read on recommendations regarding new/delete/unique_ptr here :  https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines